# How do I create a mail merge template for emails which include heading names in the document?

Tags: excel, email, ms-word, mailmerge, vba

I'm trying to mail merge data from an excel spreadsheet and want to include the heading titles and know if there is a quick way to include every field with a value in the document.

Example of data from excel

```
Name  Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4...
James   88     50    90      25
John    80           80      98
Amy     70     85            85
```

The example mail merge in word would look something like this for each person;

```
Dear James,

Score1  88
Score2  50
Score3  90
Score4  25


Dear John,

Score1  80
Score3  80
Score4  98


Dear Amy,

Score1  70
Score2  85
Score4  85
```

I don't want the heading name i.e. Score2 to appear if there's no data for that field, and this would be a repetitive task where the heading names for score1,2 etc are subject to change and so need an effective way to list them all on the document (should they contain data for that person). I'm hoping this might be done with creating a macro.

Edit:

To further clarify, I can get my document to list the Name and scores like so;

Dear «Name»

«Score1»

But I need the following...

Dear «Name»

Score1: «Score1»

Comment: What did you try so far? Where is your code? Please read [ask].

Comment: I've got the Excel list in Word's mail merge. I only know how to put score details into the document using Insert Mail Merge. I don't know how to automate putting all the headings into the Word document along with the scores.

Comment: If, as you say, the column headings could change, then I think only a (at least partial) VBA solution - is going to give you a satisfactory result. That said... Test this: insert a merge field, select it, then press Ctrl+Shift+F9. That should leave ONLY the field name (with the angled brackets). So, theoretically, you could insert each field *twice*, unlinking the first, then use Find/Replace to remove the brackets. I just gave you some VBA code to loop all the DataFields, these steps could certainly be built into that... As well as testing whether the field is empty before inserting it BTW

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge the headers - simply type them into your mailmerge main document and, if you want to suppress them when empty, employ the mergefield \b & \f switches, thus:

```
{MERGEFIELD Score1 \b "Score 1: " \f "¶
"}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. Instead of the ¶ symbol, you should use a real line/paragraph break.